# how to set an auto increment id in Android realm-java?

Tags: android

Do you know how to set auto incremental id in android realm java,i know realm at moment doesn't have support built in for this just like sq lite.

Comment: Don't ask for full code on StackOverflow, rather than do some coding work and then ask for suggestions or bug removing

Comment: share the code you already tried but not working as expected and also share the logcat if it gives an error

Comment: i have shared my code please take a look below as a solution

Answer (score 1):

Pass the name of model class which is extending RealmObject and change the column name "con_id" to id field (primary key)of your Model class.

Call this method and it will give you one id which you can use to insert any new record with new id.

```
public static long getUniqueId(Realm realm, Class className) {
            Number number = realm.where(className).max("con_id");
            if (number == null) return 1;
            else return (long) number + 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i got something working for the question but i am not sure what harm it has to the whole but i feel that its a bit slow though but anyways below is the code:
**The logic is:**

1. get the RealmObject (example DbArticle.java it extends Realmobject)
2. Check Data Object if its empty ,if its empty then make **articleID** value set to 1 else not empty then get the last highest value of **articleID** then add 1,then keep on recalling this as new data is added into realm Database.

Code:

The DbArticle.java is:

```
public class DbArticle extends RealmObject {
    private String articleTitle,articleDate,articleDescription,articleImage,articleAudioFile;
    private boolean articleIsReadYet;
    private int articleID;

    public String getArticleTitle() {
        return articleTitle;
    }

    public void setArticleTitle(String articleTitle) {
        this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
    }

    public String getArticleDate() {
        return articleDate;
    }

    public void setArticleDate(String articleDate) {
        this.articleDate = articleDate;
    }

    public String getArticleDescription() {
        return articleDescription;
    }

    public void setArticleDescription(String articleDescription) {
        this.articleDescription = articleDescription;
    }

    public String getArticleImage() {
        return articleImage;
    }

    public void setArticleImage(String articleImage) {
        this.articleImage = articleImage;
    }

    public String getArticleAudioFile() {
        return articleAudioFile;
    }

    public void setArticleAudioFile(String articleAudioFile) {
        this.articleAudioFile = articleAudioFile;
    }

    public boolean isArticleIsReadYet() {
        return articleIsReadYet;
    }

    public void setArticleIsReadYet(boolean articleIsReadYet) {
        this.articleIsReadYet = articleIsReadYet;
    }

    public int getArticleID() {
        return articleID;
    }

    public void setArticleID(int articleID) {
        this.articleID = articleID;
    }
}
```

Then i created a method called **writeArticle()** just to insert or write to realm,see below:

```
public void writeArticle(String ... args){
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        DbArticle conx = realm.createObject(DbArticle.class); // Create a new object
            conx.setArticleTitle(args[0]);
       // Log.e("xxx","--->wrote:"+args[0]);
            conx.setArticleDescription(args[1]);
            conx.setArticleDate(args[2]);
            conx.setArticleImage(args[3]);
            conx.setArticleIsReadYet(false);
            conx.setArticleAudioFile(args[4]);
       String VideoUrl=args[5];
                RealmResults<DbArticle> results = realm.where(DbArticle.class).findAll();
                    if (results.isEmpty() && results.size() < 1) {
                        final int INIT_ID = 0;
                        conx.setArticleID(INIT_ID);

                    } else {
                        final int ADD_ID = 1;
                        conx.setArticleID(
                                results.max("articleID").intValue() + ADD_ID
                        );
                    }


        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
```

so this is working for me but the **articleID** is not set with @PrimaryKey annotation please note!!!

So guys try it out and tell me the setbacks that this code has and if one can fix the code to do better.